# How to find characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ such that $A=A^n$ for some $n\geq 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I believe the characteristic polynomial is $p_A(x)=x^n-x^{n-1}$, but I don't know how we get this? I've tried applying the definition $p_A(x)=\text{det}(A-\lambda I)$ but am getting no success with the excessive notation.

Comment: How did you decide that $x^n - x^{n-1}$ should be the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What is the order of $A$?

Comment: Do you mean $x^n-x$?

Comment: The exponent of the leading term of the characteristic polynomial is equal to the order of the matrix. How do you know that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are many possibilities for the characteristic polynomial of $A$. It is true that $x^n - x^{n-1}$ is one such possibility.

**Hint:** If $A = A^n$, then for every eigenvector $v$ of $A$ we have $Av = A^n v$. What does this tell you about the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Ok thanks for that, since we deduce that $\lambda^n=\lambda$ this would imply that the eigenvalues must be either 0's and 1's? Would the algebraic multiplicities actually depend on what the matrix is itself, or can we deduce those?

Comment: There are other possibilities besides $0$ and $1$; recall that $A$ might also have complex eigenvalues. To your second question, we have no way of deducing multiplicities (however, it turns out that we can deduce that $A$ is diagonalizable).